# Can I put Applet in html code in Web view (android)

Tags: java, android, applet

I have code which have applet tag in html , i want to use this html code in `webview` in Android is that possible and if not what are the alternative way?

Comment: *"is that possible .."* No, not really. I don't think Java applets were ***ever*** supported by Android, and now they're being phased out of browsers for desk-top computers. *".. if not what are the alternative way?"* Possibly JS. What does the applet do?

Comment: its have some java classes to read from card reader for smart card